# Quick way to hide rows in datagridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a window forms application in which I need to hide and show rows of a datagridView quite frequently. Currently and using a loop

```
for (int i=0;i<grid.Rows.Count;i++){
    grid.Rows[i].Visible = false;
}
```

But this is making my UI too slow, is there a faster way to do this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just hide the entire DataGridView?

Comment: If it is databound you can filter out rows. If you make the dgv doublebuffered it may also be faster.

Comment: @danish yes that's what I want to do that but I can only hide rows, not the grid. Is it possible to hide all rows in one go?

Comment: @TaW no it's not databound

Comment: You will need loop through all the rows. AFAIK, there is no alternative except for hiding the entire control/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all rows after storing them in a list and add them back as needed:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = null;


// prepare list
rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
// copy rows to list
rows.AddRange(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>());
// remove them all
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


// add them back:
dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
// clean up
rows.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is if you are using the DataSource as input:

For normal operation:

```
grid.DataSource = yourList;
```

In case you want to hide certain elements:

```
grid.DataSource = yourList.Where(x => x.SomeBool).ToArray();
```

Note:

Sometimes the datasource isn't fully renewed like this, therefore you could try to set it to null first, resulting in:

```
grid.DataSource = null;
grid.DataSource = yourList.Where(x => x.SomeBool).ToArray();
```

Comment: ty for the answer but my grid is not bound to  a datasource

Answer (score 0):

VB.net rather than C#:

Turning on DoubleBuffering will improve your performance:

`dgvMain.[GetType].GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(dgvMain, True, Nothing)`

Also `dgvMain.SuspendLayout()` and `dgvMain.ResumeLayout()` may help.

I found an additional boost in performance by hiding all the DataGridView Columns (and the DataGridView**Row** Headers) before running the row hiding function and then making the columns / headers visible again after.

-OO-